# Regarding PThread's and PThread Barriers

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, pthread-barriers

I'm writing an SMT program, and I'm trying to workaround an interesting problem.

I need all my functions to exit together, however some of the threads get stuck at barriers, even when i don't want them to.

My question is: what happens when i delete a barrier? Do threads stuck at the barrier release? Is there a way to signal a release to a certain barrier, even if the number of threads at the barrier hasn't been achieved?

Thanks

Comment: Don't block a thread on a barrier if you don't want it to be blocked on a barrier. Just code exactly what you need.

Comment: @EOF thanks, it confirms what i though and what caf wrote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not legal to call `pthread_barrier_destroy()` if there's any threads blocked on the barrier.

When your thread decides to exit early in a situation where other threads could be waiting on it at a barrier, it should call `pthread_barrier_wait()` before exiting.